# Index error in Python( index out of range)

Tags: python, index-error

```
given_number=str(input("Enter the number:"))
total=str(0)
num=0
while num<=len(given_number):
       total+=given_number[num]
       num+=1
print(total)
```

Got indexerror.Where is the fault?

Comment: use `num<len(given_number)` as indexing starts at `0` and ends at `len(given_number)-1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your while loop. Apparently, your loop iterates through 0 to the length of your input string while the maximum index of 0 base list/array/string is

> len(given_number)-1

Modify your code like this.

```
   given_number=str(input("Enter the number:"))
   total=str(0)
   num=0
   while num<len(given_number): # Note: I use < not <=
       total+=given_number[num]
       num+=1
   print(total)
```

I hope it will help you to overcome your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a `"0"` to the input string. you can directly do like

```
print("0"+input())
```

Instead using the most lengthy method to append something to a string.